# Use jQuery to dynamically alter Form GET target on Submit

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I would like to submit a form, specifically an input field to a URL based on the input field's value using GET.

Example: Input field value is "**test**". Submit GETs www.myurl.com/Products/Search/**test**

Example: Input field value is **empty**. Submit GETs www.myurl.com/Products/Search/

Example: Input field value is "**123**". Submit GETs www.myurl.com/Products/Search/**123**

How could I do this using jQuery? Probably intercepting the submit..?? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    this.action += $('#myInput').val();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: This works great, except that it appends the input still also as ?input=value (e.g. www.myurl.com/Products/Search/test?search=test). How can I get rid of the query string part?

Comment: try removing the #myInput after getting value. $("#myInput").remove()

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: That kinda worked, but its clearly visible that I'm removing the input (visibly disappears before submit) which would confuse the hell out of users :(  --- very cool workaround attempt though. The idea made me smile. Any idea how to do this without making the input disappear?

Comment: try $('#myInput').text() instead.